# MomentJS check if next day and get days apart

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I check if it's the next day?

```
const startDate = moment(item.start_time);
const endDate = moment(item.end_time);
const dateDiff = startDate.diff(endDate, 'days', true)
const nextDay = dateDiff > 1
```

It works for dates like Aug 14th 2PM to Aug 14th 4PM however it doesn't work for dates like Aug 14th 4PM to Aug 14th 2PM.

How can I fix it?

If possible I would like to get the number of days apart they are.

```
const startDate = moment(item.start_time);
const endDate = moment(item.end_time);
const dateDiff = startDate.diff(endDate, 'days', true) mod 1
```

Comment: `start_time` format timestamp or date object?

Comment: it's a javascript date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getDate` & `setDate` methods to increase the current date object by exactly a day. Afterwards you need just compare the date year, month and date.

```js
var isNextDay = function(next, current) {
  var date = new Date(current);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  
  return (date.getFullYear() === next.getFullYear()) && (date.getMonth() === next.getMonth()) && (date.getDate() === next.getDate());
};

var currentDay = new Date('2016-05-31 16:00:00');
var nextDay = new Date('2016-06-01 14:00:00');
console.log('It is ' + (isNextDay(nextDay, currentDay) ? '' : 'not ') + 'the next day');
```

Comment: what if it was May 31st and June 1st?

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
var currentDay =new moment('2016-05-31 16:00:00');
var nextDay = new moment('2016-06-01 14:00:00');

console.log('It is ' + (nextDay.isSame(currentDay.add(1, 'days'), 'd') === true ? '' : 'not ') + 'the next day');
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLn9rwkb/)